# How to resolve KotlinReflectionInternalError when using a custom adapter with Moshi?

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, moshi

I use `Moshi` for JSON conversions.

I have a custom adapter for converting `LocalDateTime` to JSON:

```
class LocalDateTimeAdapter {
    @ToJson
    fun toJson(value: LocalDateTime): String {
        return value.toString()
    }

    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(value: String): LocalDateTime {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(value)
    }
}
```

I use it like so:

```
val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
        .addLast(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .add(LocalDateTimeAdapter())
        .build()
    
val jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(MyModel::class.java)
val json = jsonAdapter.toJson(model)
```

This works fine for the `debug` build variant. The application crashes for other build variants where debugging is disabled with the following exception.

> kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KotlinReflectionInternalError: Could not compute caller for function: public constructor

I've put in hours trying to resolve this but to no avail. As far as I understand this is because of `proguard`. I've tried putting the following in the `proguard` file:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.moshi.* <methods>;
}
-keep @com.squareup.moshi.JsonQualifier interface *
-dontwarn org.jetbrains.annotations.**
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
-keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {
    public <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @com.squareup.moshi.FromJson *;
    @com.squareup.moshi.ToJson *;
}

-keepclassmembers class com.squareup.moshi.internal.Util {
    private static java.lang.String getKotlinMetadataClassName();
}

-keepnames @kotlin.Metadata class com.myapp.domain.model.**
-keep class com.myapp.domain.model.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.myapp.domain.model.** { *; }
```

Comment: I've got the exact same issue as this ... did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: No, I had to switch to using `gson`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My issue is with some generated kotlin code from openapi-generator (which also uses moshi). 

What I'm going to do is try to reduce the scope of the problem and raise an issue in that project, with a complete example.

Comment: I'm getting somewhere with this. I've had to add `-dontobfuscate` to my proguard rules, and thereafter it's complaining about random classes that are included in my project, so I'm going through and adding `-keep` clauses for these. I'm still not there yet, but it's definitely positive as the stack trace is changing each time I add a proguard rule, so I hope there is light at the end of the tunnel

Comment: Ok, I ultimately hit a roadblock which I couldn't pass. I'd turned off obfuscation, shrinking and optimisation in proguard, but still got the same "Could not compute caller for function" with `kotlin.reflect.jvm.ReflectJvmMapping.getJavaMethod`. At this point I decided to ditch Moshi and do the same as you with the Gson route. So annoying, this should just work. Now getting on much better with Gson. Thanks again.